# How can we define the default configuration values in one place and use it for all the data tables in the application

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

Can I define the default configuration values in one place and use it for all the data table in the application ?

Instead of defining like this twice, language values can define in one place.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    data: data,
    serverSide: true,
    pageLength: 25,
    ajax : "test.php",
    language: {
        "emptyTable": "ليست هناك بيانات متاحة في الجدول",
        "loadingRecords": "جارٍ التحميل...",
        "lengthMenu": "أظهر _MENU_ مدخلات",
        "zeroRecords": "لم يعثر على أية سجلات",
        "info": "إظهار _START_ إلى _END_ من أصل _TOTAL_ مدخل",
        "infoEmpty": "يعرض 0 إلى 0 من أصل 0 سجل",
        "infoFiltered": "(منتقاة من مجموع _MAX_ مُدخل)",
        "search": "ابحث:"
    }
})
```

Here language values are the same default values repeated.

```
$('#example1').DataTable({
    data: data
    pageLength: 10,
    language: {
        "emptyTable": "ليست هناك بيانات متاحة في الجدول",
        "loadingRecords": "جارٍ التحميل...",
        "lengthMenu": "أظهر _MENU_ مدخلات",
        "zeroRecords": "لم يعثر على أية سجلات",
        "info": "إظهار _START_ إلى _END_ من أصل _TOTAL_ مدخل",
        "infoEmpty": "يعرض 0 إلى 0 من أصل 0 سجل",
        "infoFiltered": "(منتقاة من مجموع _MAX_ مُدخل)",
        "search": "ابحث:"
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you try creating a variable, before the DataTable initialization? `var lang_values = { "emptyTable": "...", ... };` and then use that variable in the DataTable: `language: lang_values`. If your tables are on different pages, then passing in the value to each page depends on the framework you are using.